Zoom and keep shape centered at mouse pointer
I'm trying to implement the zoom function for an application that draws shapes on the screen. These shapes are created in millimeters converted to pixels depending on the dpi value.
The drawing is done in a pictureBox that is placed in a panel that has Autoscroll true.
Each zoom increases the size of the pictureBox horizontally and vertically.
When I zoom in using the mouse wheel scroll the vertical scroll bar is also moved while the horizontal scroll bar remains unchanged by the wheel scroll.
For this reason the shape remains in the correct position on the screen horizontally, but vertically it moves down step by step scroll by scroll.
So I need a function to compensate for this movement.
My code looks something like this:
private int deltaScroll = 0;
    private float previousZoom;
    private void viewport_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        mousePoint = viewport.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
        
        deltaScroll += e.Delta / 120;
        if (e.Delta > 0)
        {
            ZoomIn();
        }
        else if (e.Delta < 0)
        {
            ZoomOut();
        }
    }

    private void ZoomIn()
    {
        if (zoomFactor < 20.0f) // Prevent zooming in too much
        {
            previousZoom = zoomFactor; // Store the old zoom factor
            zoomFactor += 0.2f;
            ApplyZoom();

            // Calculate and apply scroll offsets
            CompensateScroll(previousZoom, zoomFactor);
        }
    }

    private void ZoomOut()
    {
        if (zoomFactor > 0.21f) // Prevent zooming out too much
        {
            previousZoom = zoomFactor; // Store the old zoom factor
            zoomFactor -= 0.2f;
            ApplyZoom();

            // Calculate and apply scroll offsets
            CompensateScroll(previousZoom, zoomFactor);
        }
    }

    private void CompensateScroll(float previousZoom, float newZoom)
    {
        int mouseX = viewport.HorizontalScroll.Value + mousePoint.X;
        int mouseY = viewport.VerticalScroll.Value + mousePoint.Y;

        // Calculate scaling factor
        float scaleFactor = newZoom / previousZoom;

        // Calculate new scroll deltas, applying the wheel delta to vertical scroll compensation
        int deltaX = (int)((mouseX * scaleFactor) - mouseX);
        int deltaY = (int)((mouseY * scaleFactor) - mouseY);

        // Clamp new scroll values to stay within bounds
        int newScrollX = MathExtensions.Clamp(viewport.HorizontalScroll.Value + deltaX, viewport.HorizontalScroll.Minimum, viewport.HorizontalScroll.Maximum);
        int newScrollY = MathExtensions.Clamp(viewport.VerticalScroll.Value + deltaY, viewport.VerticalScroll.Minimum, viewport.VerticalScroll.Maximum);

        // Apply adjusted scroll positions
        viewport.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(newScrollX, newScrollY);
    }

    private void ApplyZoom()
    {
        foreach (var shape in shapes)
        {
            shape.ZoomFactor = zoomFactor;
        }

        double percentage = 100.0 * zoomFactor;
        toolStripLabel2.Text = percentage.ToString("00") + "%";

        SetPictureBoxSize(); // Set zoomed pictureBox size (width*zoomFactor, height*zoomFactor)
        pictureBox1.Invalidate(); // Refresh
    }

The following code seems to work very close to what I want:
 private int preZoomVerticalScroll;
    private void viewport_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        mousePoint = viewport.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
        preZoomVerticalScroll = (int)(mousePoint.Y * (zoomFactor - 1));

        if (ModifierKeys == Keys.Control)
        {
            if (e.Delta > 0)
            {
                ZoomIn();
            }
            else if (e.Delta < 0)
            {
                ZoomOut();
            }
        }
    }

    float previousZoom;
    private void ZoomIn()
    {
        if (zoomFactor < 20.0f) // Prevent zooming in too much
        {
            previousZoom = zoomFactor; // Store the old zoom factor
            zoomFactor *= 1.2f;
            ApplyZoom();
            // Calculate and apply scroll offsets
            CompensateScroll(previousZoom, zoomFactor);
        }
    }

    private void ZoomOut()
    {
        if (zoomFactor > 0.21f) // Prevent zooming out too much
        {
            previousZoom = zoomFactor; // Store the old zoom factor
            zoomFactor /= 1.2f;
            ApplyZoom();

            // Calculate and apply scroll offsets
            CompensateScroll(previousZoom, zoomFactor);
        }
    }

    private void CompensateScroll(float previousZoom, float newZoom)
    {
        // Get the current scroll position (both X and Y)
        int currentScrollX = viewport.HorizontalScroll.Value;
        int currentScrollY = preZoomVerticalScroll;

        // Get the mouse position relative to the viewport, including current scroll offsets
        int mouseX = mousePoint.X + currentScrollX;
        int mouseY = mousePoint.Y + currentScrollY;

        // Calculate scale factors for X and Y axes based on zoom
        float scaleFactor = newZoom / previousZoom;

        // Calculate the deltas for both X and Y axes (how much the content should move after zoom)
        int deltaX = (int)(mouseX * scaleFactor) - mouseX;
        int deltaY = (int)(mouseY * scaleFactor) - mouseY;

        // Adjust the scroll position based on the deltas, ensuring they stay within bounds
        int newScrollX = MathExtensions.Clamp(currentScrollX + deltaX, viewport.HorizontalScroll.Minimum, viewport.HorizontalScroll.Maximum);
        int newScrollY = MathExtensions.Clamp(currentScrollY + deltaY, viewport.VerticalScroll.Minimum, viewport.VerticalScroll.Maximum);
        // Set the new scroll position for the viewport
        viewport.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(newScrollX, newScrollY);

    }

    private void ApplyZoom()
    {
        foreach (var shape in shapes)
        {
            shape.ZoomFactor = zoomFactor;
        }

        double percentage = 100.0 * zoomFactor;
        toolStripLabel2.Text = percentage.ToString("00") + "%";

        SetPictureBoxSize(); // Set zoomed pictureBox size (width*zoomFactor, height*zoomFactor)

    }


Note: you will get a more natural behavior if you zoom in or out by a constant factor instead of adding/subtracting a value. E.g. zoomFactor *= 1.15f; or zoomFactor /= 1.15f;. With +/- it will zoom fast when the zoomFactor is small and slowly when it is large.
